# Findall give me same items in different source

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I am getting source code from my selenium driver in a while true loop I am using regex findall and getting list of items that I need but when the page change with source findall give me old page items I am trying everything and I am sure it is because of regex I checked the string that I use in regex it is refreshing with page but something happen in findall and it is giving old items. (Note:Page Source code that I used to in regex.findall has more than 1700 text-line)

My code hierarchy

```
while True:
        a=browser_getsourcecode
        listitem=r.findall('...',a)
        for x in listitem:
                print(x)
```

I am working on code for hours and I asking to question from my phone so I can’t share code for now but when I wake up I will share it too.

Update sorry for being late.

```
from  selenium import webdriver
from os import system, name 
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import os
import time
import re


dirpath = os.getcwd()
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
options.add_argument("--test-type")
driver_path =dirpath+"\chromedriver.exe"
print(driver_path)
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=driver_path,options=options)
browser.get("https://www.instagram.com/?hl=tr")

y=0
lastlist = list()
result = list()
while True:
    html = browser.page_source
    a = html.count("stroflstrore")
    if a > 1 :
        input("Start to search...")
        break
    else:
        time.sleep(5)
        print("Login Waiting...")
while True:

    result.clear()
    html = browser.page_source
    b = html.encode('ascii', 'ignore')
    tml = b.decode('utf-8')
    print(tml)
    print("\n...................................................................................................")
    result = re.findall('"video_url":"(.+?)","video_view_count":', tml)
    cc=len(result)
    print("cc:"+str(cc))
    if cc != 0:
        ii=1
        while ii<=cc:

            result[ii-1]=str(result[ii-1]).replace("\\","")
            ii = ii + 1


    resultwout = list(set(result))
    c=len(resultwout)
    print("c:"+str(c))

    if c != 0:
        i = 1
        while i<=c:

            if not resultwout[i-1] in lastlist:

                print(resultwout[i-1])
                lastlist.append(resultwout[i-1])
            else:
                print(resultwout[i-1])
                y=y + 2000
                browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, "+str(y)+")")

            i = i + 1
            print("i:"+str(i))
    else:
        y=y + 2000
        browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, "+str(y)+")")
        print("Waiting Video...")
    time.sleep(2)
```

Basically my system working like scrolling down on your instagram page and if you found something interesting for you share with your friends gives you videos links. It is working but just temporary when the page first open program get the links of videos but when you scroll down and even page source code change it doesn't effect re.findall result.

Comment: As it stands, with the given information, not answerable.

Comment: Please provide more information.

Comment: Waiting for you to wake up :)

Comment: I added update sorry for being late :D